# php-mysql count() query repeating results

Tags: php, mysql

Using `count()` query with php will cause the result display in looping. How to fix this issue?

phpmyadmin has no problem showing the sum but can't apply it to php code.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db'); 
if (!$conn) { die('db error'); };
$result = mysqli_query($conn, '
select count(*) as x from users
');

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['x'];
```

Expect result :

```
2
```

Actual output :

```
2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222...
```

Comment: why `count(*)` ? try `count( distinct YOUR_PK)`

Comment: absolutely sure this is the complete code? (...and there isn't a while around $row=mysqli_fetch...?)

Comment: Is this the entirety of your script? Is this embedded inside a loop? Can you try change your echo to `echo $row['x'] . ' - ';` to see if it outputs that dash as a separator. This will indicate whether that block of code is being looped (querying and echoing repeatedly), or if it is $row['x'] that has all those 2s (unlikely).

Comment: @Mohammad Be careful with that query. Unless the RDBMS is smart enough to realize that `distinct` of a PK is pointless and ignores the `distinct` requirement, adding "distinct" to the count of a PK will just add overhead to the query. Why instruct the RDBMS to do the extra work of checking for distinct values in a column that can only contain distinct values? Additionally, `count(distinct ...)` has a specific use case, and is not synonymous with `count(*)`. The OP may want to know how many individual rows are in the table, and not how many instances of a particular group are in the table.

Comment: Edit : Suddenly my codes work back, now it displays '2' instead of '222222222222222222...'. So weird with my php script.

Comment: @RToyo good point, thanks for explanation

Comment: @RToyo my code indeed inside a loop, but its 1 loop. But anyway it works now.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as x FROM users")) {
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $number = $row['x'];
    }
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
$conn->close();
if(isset($number)){
    echo $number;
}
```

Comment: how does this address the OP's problem?

Comment: Sorry, it's very nice but this doesn't actually contain a resolution.

Comment: It works! Thanks, it displays '2' now. Why my original code not working?